# Are there some problems with my proxy in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, axios

I want to get some information from an Api, which is written by others. I use axios to request the Api. When I use Webpack to pack, it would have the problem of cross domain. I try to use proxy, which is provided by Webpack, it still shows me some problem.

`Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https`

I follow this to write my webpack.config.js

https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy:{
            '/v2': {
                target: 'http://api.douban.com',
                secure:false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                pathRewrite: {
                    '^/v2': '/v2'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    entry: ['whatwg-fetch','./App/app.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dest'),
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {   test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders:['css-loader']
            },
            {   test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
                loaders: ['file-loader']
            },
            {   test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        console: true,
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    }
};
```

Here is my axios request:

```
 axios.post({
 url: '/v2/movie/in_theaters',
 })
 .then((res)=>{
 //console.log(res.data)
 //data=res.data;
 this.setState({data:"success"})
 })
 .catch((err)=>{
 this.setState({data:"err"})
 })
```

I use React, so I try to understand whether Success by setState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the `http://api.douban.com` hosted?

You need to update its server configuration to allow requests sent from a different origin (probably localhost).

Basically, requests sent from something hosted on `douban.com` are probably enabled by default, but not from somewhere else unless explicitly allowed on the server configuration.

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: It is not my server, so I couldn't update its server configuration.By the way, thank you very much, I've learnt a lot.